# Using EF Core migrations with existing EF6 migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm currently trying to refactor an existing .NET Framework enterprise project into .NET Core. I've gotten the classes moved to Core, as well as set up the Fluent Configurations for all the objects.

We are using EF's Migrations to manage the database, so we have our stack of migrations that exist in the `__MigrationHistory` table EF6 created. Now with EF Core, that wants to create an `__EFMigrationsHistory` table instead.

Is there any way to get EF Core to recognize all of the migrations that existed in that other table?

Comment: So, you want to recreate _same_ migrations but in.NET Core code?

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov Yes. If we are going against an existing database, the migrations should just add on to what exists, not try to create everything. If we have a new database, then it'd be fine to create all the tables.

Comment: (My personal preference would be to not use the Migrations at all, but that decision is out of my hands.)

Comment: As a link to the Microsoft docs for this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/porting/port-code#existing-migrations - recommended is basically just create new migrations, and then blank them out as the difference between EF6 and EF Core migrations make them not too compatible

Comment: Thanks @Gibbon. I couldn't find that when I was searching. Do you want to make an answer with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to directly re-use migrations is not something recommended - it is suggested that you instead add new migrations and then delete out the Up / Down changes to essentially reset the migration to the current model / database configuration as suggested in the [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/porting/port-code#existing-migrations) on the top